# Sign and update Visual Studio Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing, visual-studio-2019, vsix, vsixmanifest

So it seems as a pretty easy Task, I created a VSIX which I uploaded a few days ago. Some days later I fixed some issues and now I want to update the extension on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/).

I went ahead and took a look at the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-update-a-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2019) which states the following:

> Unsigned all user extensions do not get updated automatically. You should always sign your extensions.

So therefor I went on an tried to sign my VSIX as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/signing-vsix-packages?view=vs-2019). Which tells me to do the following:

> Search for VSIXSignTool from VisualStudioExtensibility and install the NuGet package.

After downloading the package, I searched for the given location which should be in your `project's local packages location`. Which makes me wonder, cause I do not have any local packages folder for this project. Furthermore I should sign my extension with the following command:

`VSIXSignTool.exe sign /f <certfile> /p <password> <VSIXfile>`

Which makes me wonder, what kind of certificate that should be, what should be the password be, a new password?

Anyway, lets assume I somehow mange to do that, how would I 'update' the extension than? Just upload it again as a new package with a new VSIX-Id?

To sum it up, this are my questions:

- How/Where do I download the `VSIXSignTool`
- What parameters do I need to pass into the `VSIXSignTool` command provided above
- How do you really update the extension on the marketplace and do I need a new VSIX Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first try to update your extension without signing. Just increase the version number and on the marketplace site click Manage - ... (More Actions) - Edit - Upload Extension/Edit package.

VSIXSignTool requires a code signing certificate that needs to be purchased.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.